# How to Use JDO with Google App Engine Modules Java

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I'm trying to use JDO for datastore, in GAE Java modules app.
I have created two dynamic web projects with GAE runtime. Created an EAR project, add the two dynamic web projects to EAR.
Then tried "run on server".
I got the following error.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "MyBeanClass" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

I tried enabling the JPA facet also.

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: and you read the message? your class hasn't been enhanced, so enhance it. An search of GAE docs would tell you about this

Comment: Have you annotated the class and run the enhancer? please include your class source and the build tool you are using.

Comment: I have annotated the classes. Its working fine, if it is a GAE web prorect.
To use modules I have created Dynamic web project, and copied my files.
I'm using Data Nucleus Enhancer, How ever it is not getting triggered.
how to make data nucleus get triggered whenever a jdo class is modified?

Comment: The DataNucleus project provides various tools (Maven, Eclipse plugins) to perform enhancement. Their documentation tells you how to use them. They are, of course, nothing to do with Google's "GAE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after lot of trail and errors.

I just wanted to post the solution so that it might help others.

Creating a Dynamic Web Project and enabling JPA didn't work for me.

I created a Dynamic web project, while creating selected, Google App engine with JPA. It solved the problem.

Thanks..!!